# Recurring events on a calendar : RFC 5545 Javascript parsing 

Tags: javascript, parsing, icalendar, rrule

I need to integrate recurring events into an adapted version of full-calendar that has an added javascript module which allows offline event browsing.

I'm looking for a javascript library that can parse recurring events according to RFC 5545.

I need to be able to list all recurring events that occur between 2 dates (start date and end date), using RRULE and EXDATE and interpreting daily, weekly, monthly and yearly recurrences.

I've spent hours searching for something to no aval, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel....Can anyone please point me in the right direction for an existing javascript parser?

Answer (score 4):

I checked into skyporters rrule_parser and found that it doesn't support all of the rules (particularly, it won't do BYDAY properly).  I found a fantastic alternative:

https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule

They are actively supporting this library and have a great [demo website](https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/) that shows all of the functionality.  You can parse from either 5545 format or plain text (using the nlp extension). It is feature packed and, as far as I can tell, fully functioning.

Answer (score 1):

look into https://github.com/skyporter/rrule_parser.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

here is a recurrence widget for jquery, which parses/creates RFC5545 compatible recurrence strings.

https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js

it does not expanding of a recurrence rule into occurrence dates, though. but it includes a python server, which can do it for you, using python-dateutil: http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Answer (score 0):

I needed this functionality myself, along with time zone support, so I made a typescript/javascript library: [rSchedule](https://gitlab.com/john.carroll.p/rschedule).

Currently supports all ICAL recurrence rules except BYSETPOS, BYWEEKNO, and BYYEARDAY. Supports serialization to/from ICAL format along with a ton of extra stuff.

Example:

```
const rule = new RRule({
  frequency: 'YEARLY',
  byMonthOfYear: [2, 6],
  byDayOfWeek: ['SU', ['MO', 3]],
  start: new Date(2010,1,7),
}, {
  dateAdapter: StandardDateAdapter
})

let index = 0;
for (const date of rule.occurrences()) {
  date.toISOString()
  index++

  if (index > 10) break;
}

rule.occurrences({
  start: new Date(2010,5,7),
  take: 5
})
  .toArray()
  .map(date => date.toISOString())
```