# React FullCalendar - How to get upcoming dates if they are not for a few months

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, rrule

I am working on adding the [FullCalendar with React](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) to my project and working on getting the upcoming dates. But with the way it seems the CalendarAPI has it set up, I am not able to retrieve the nearest calendar events if they are not displayed on the calendar UI.

The `.getEvents();` method does not return all the events, only those events which are present in he current view. I need to return ALL events, not just what is in the current view.

Example of desired result. Let's say I don't have a calendar event until March of next year So the UI would not have anything in it, but I still want to be able to get that March event because that is the next upcoming event.

How do I retrieve that? This logic works if I do have events this month, but if I don't have any until several months away, I can't return those.

```
let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, '')

useEffect(() => {
    let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();
    
    // If there arent events for a few months, what do I change in this to return those events?
    // The CalendarAPI seems to only want to return what is currently visible.
    let events = calendarApi.getEvents();
    let calendarEvents = events.map(i => i.toPlainObject());
    let filteredEvents = calendarEvents.filter(i => i.start >= todayStr);
    let sorted = filteredEvents.sort((a, b) => a.start.localeCompare(b.start));
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [calendarRef]);

const INITIAL_EVENTS = [
    {
        id: 321,
        title: 'Last Friday of every month',
        color: 'orange',
        rrule: {
          freq: 'monthly',
          interval: 1,
          byweekday: [CALENDAR_ENUM.Friday],
          bysetpos: -1,
          dtstart: '2022-12-01',
          until: '2028-06-01'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 321,
        title: 'First Friday of every Third month',
        color: 'pink',
        rrule: {
          freq: 'monthly',
          interval: 3,
          byweekday: ['fr'],
          bysetpos: 1,
          dtstart: '2022-12-01',
          until: '2028-06-01'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 220,
        title: 'MWF Every other week',
        rrule: {
          freq: 'weekly',
          interval: 2,
          byweekday: [CALENDAR_ENUM.Monday, CALENDAR_ENUM.Wednesday, CALENDAR_ENUM.Friday],
          dtstart: '2022-12-01',
          until: '2028-06-01'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 22,
        title: 'One Day',
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        // Any custom parameters will be put under extendedProps
        location: 'Test Location', 
        otherDetails: [{objectTitle: 'Title', objectValue: 200}], 
        AssignedComponent: "All",
        Category: ["Budget", "Travel Pay"],
        // End Custom Parameters
        rrule: {
          freq: 'daily', // required
          count: 1,
          dtstart: '2022-12-25T10:30:00',
          until: '2028-10-25'
        }
    },
]

    <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, rrulePlugin]}
        headerToolbar={{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        }}
        ref={calendarRef}
        initialView='dayGridMonth'
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS}
        select={createEventFromSelectedDate}
        eventContent={renderEventContent}
        eventClick={showHideAddEventHandler}
        eventsSet={handleEvents}
    />
```

EDIT: I don't really need ALL events. But I do need a way to get the upcoming events. If I do not have any events for a few months I still need to be able to see those next events to be displayed on my dashboard. If there are events in the current view, then the `.getEvents()` method will work for grabbing the next upcoming events. But if there are 0 events this month, it does not work.

Comment: `I need to return ALL events`...presumably you would have originally got the events from an API or database or something? So maybe the best thing is to ask that data source for the information. But really, _all_ the events? What about when your application and calendar has existed for a few years and there are thousands stored from earlier times...are you really interested in them all? What are you actually trying to achieve? You mention "upcoming" events, so maybe you actually only want the ones within a certain date range (e.g. from today up to a few weeks ahead, or something)?

Comment: You're right, I don't really need ALL events. But I do need a way to get the upcoming events. In the DB the events will be stored the same way they are in INITIAL_EVENTS in the code above. They will not be stored as individual events, because if you have an event that repeats every weekday, then instead of one line item in the DB you suddenly have 260 line items. So no, I can't get the next upcoming from the DB since it wont say anything about the next upcoming. But if I do not have any events for a few months I still need to be able to see those next events to be displayed on my dashboard.

Comment: Realistically then you're probably going to have to have some separate code which can parse the rrule and work out the resulting events that are needed for any given time period. Fullcalendar can't do that for you, but presumably somewhere in its codebase there must be some code which does more or less exactly that (so it can work out the events it needs to display on the calendar). Or perhaps someone else already has an rrule deriving code as a separate bit of code or tool which you can use / copy / modify.

Comment: Would you have any idea on where to start looking into that? There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this issue even though I have come across other posts with a similar question. And none of those have an answer.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103886/recurring-events-on-a-calendar-rfc-5545-javascript-parsing)? Or if none of that helps, I'd start googling "Javascript parse rrule" or similar. Fullcalendar relies on https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule to help with rrule parsing, so I'd expect you can use it independently. Or if you'd prefer to to this in your server-side code I'd expect there's probably a similar library for whatever language you use.